# ChicagoBoss get last entity

Tags: mongodb, erlang, chicagoboss

I'm a new one in ChicagoBoss and Erlang. And I have dumb question:
How can I get last entity from db? Something like `User.last` in Rails.

Comment: Sort descending, limit 1.

Comment: Could you please write an example?

Comment: Sorry -- I've never used either Erlang or ChicagoBoss. The way to implement `last` in MongoDB is as I described it.

Comment: And, having just looked at the docs/source really briefly: https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-erlang, I'm not sure it's a robust enough driver to actually do the operations I suggested. It hasn't even been updated in a year.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **find_last** BossDB function:

```
boss_db:find_last(type).
```

Query for the last BossRecord of type *type*

```
boss_db:find_last(type, [{foo, 'equals', <<"abc">>}, {bar, 'equals', 123}]).
```

Query for the last BossRecord of type *type* matching all of the given conditions.

Full API: http://www.chicagoboss.org/api-db.html

Comment: From the web page you linked: "Currently Tokyo Tyrant, Mnesia, MySQL, and PostgreSQL are supported." The question was about MongoDB.

Comment: From BossDB github page (https://github.com/ChicagoBoss/boss_db): "Supported databases: NEW DynamoDB (experimental), Mnesia, **MongoDB**,  MySQL, PostgreSQL, Riak, Tokyo Tyrant". I used BossDB with MongoDB in my project and this is worked fine.

Comment: From the library: `find_last(Type) -> return_one(find(Type, [], [{limit, 1}, descending])).` Nicely matches what I'd said needed to be done in my first comment. :) Also -- to note, if a field is chosen that isn't sorted already, MongoDB must sort in memory, which may be slow, depending on the size of the collection.

Comment: Yes, of course your first comment is right :) I just showed which function does it.